# Lifetime per method call and Parameter injection with Unity

Tags: c#, parameters, inversion-of-control, unity-container, code-injection

I am trying to work with an IoC Container (Unity) and by that trying to create a library which does some UDP communication for me.

Basically I got 3 classes:

- a class UdpClientAdapter which implements the following interface

  ```
  public interface IUdpClient
  {
      Task<UdpReceiveResult> ReceiveAsync();
      Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] datagram, int bytes);
      Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] datagram, int bytes, IPEndPoint endPoint);
      Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] datagram, int bytes, string hostname, int port);
  }
  ```
- a class Communicator which does some encoding/decoding, checksum checks, etc which implements the following interface

  ```
  public interface  ICommunicator
  {
      Task<int> SendAsync(int command, object dataObject = null);
      Task<int> SendAsync(int command, IEnumerable<byte> data);
      Task<T> ReceiveAsync<T>();
  }
  ```
- and a third class 'Controller' which implements the following (simplified) interface

  ```
  public interface IController
  {
      Task Start();
      Task Stop();
      Task<MachineStatus> ReadMachineStatus();
  }
  ```

The constructor of the communicator is

```
public Communicator(IUdpClient udpClient)
{
    this.udpclient = udpClient;
}
```

So the IoC-Container which instantiates this class injects - and creates - the dependency to the UdpClient.
My problem lies in the controller class. Since I am working with async methods I want that every call to a method of the controller gets its own Communicator (and therefore UdpClient) instance. Do I just use container.Resolve() then?

My second question is how I would handle a parameter for the Communicator class? In my case I need to set the UdpServer to connect to, i.e. a field of type IpEndPoint. Should I just extend the ICommunicator interface with a setter for that field or pass it somehow in the constructor (how?).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Since I am working with async methods I want that every call to a method of the controller gets its own Communicator

To me this is a big smell. What consumers of an abstraction is concerned, there should only be one instance of such abstraction. Or let me put it differently, such abstraction should not have any noticable statefulness. Stateful abstractions complicate your consumers. It could also mean that you are leaking implementation details from the `Communicator` implementation through the abstraction into the consumer. Ask yourself this: does every `ICommunicator` implementation require there to be one implementation per `Controller`?

There are multiple solutions here. Either you change the implementation of `Communicator` in such way that it becomes stateless in such way that `Controller` can work with a single instance, or -in case statefulness can't be prevented- hide `Communicator` behind a Virtual Proxy. Such Virtual Proxy can create a new `Communicator` on each method call. For instance:

```
public interface CommunicatorProxy : ICommunicator
{
    private readonly Func<ICommunicator> factory;
    public CommunicatorProxy(Func<ICommunicator> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public Task<int> SendAsync(int c, object d) => factory().SendAsync(c, d);
    public Task<int> SendAsync(int c, IEnumerable<byte> d) => factory().SendAsync(c, d);
    public Task<T> ReceiveAsync<T>() => factory().ReceiveAsync<T>();
}
```

Comment: I guess I can not change it to a stateless because my communication works in a Request->Answer way.
If one message is send, then i expect an answer. With async (or different threads) I can not guarantee that, therefore I want an own UdpClient for each request. I tried my implementation before with only a single instance of communicator and it did fail because I could not guarantee that I receive the correct answer for my request.. at least unless I dont work with some kind of common buffer/queue

Comment: From my understanding your proposed approach does not help me either.
I need to guarantee that all Send/Receive actions of one method of the 'Controller' are handled by the same Communicator.
For example the 'ReadMachineStatus()' method consists of several Send and Receive operations. I have to make sure that I only receive the answers of the corresponding method (and for example not of some other method call to 'Stop', etc)